# toggle effect in jquery

Tags: jquery, button, input, toggle

I wrote a code :

```
$('.Edit').live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).text().valueOf()=="Save"){
        alert('sauvegarder..');
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".d"+id).prop('enabled', false);
        $(".d"+id).css("background-color","#FFF");
        $(".d"+id).css("border-color","black");
        $(this).text('Save').button("refresh");
    } else if($(this).text().valueOf()=="Edit") {
        alert('editer..');
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".d"+id).prop('disabled', false);
        $(".d"+id).css("background-color","#FFF");
        $(".d"+id).css("border-color","red");
        $(this).text('Save').button("refresh");
    }
}
```

And it has this function : The button is normally on 'Edit' mode, when i click all the input element become enabled so i can write stuff in them and in the same time the button name change to 'Save'. When i click on Save, the input become disabled and i cannot write in them anymore. But when i do this code, it makes all in the same time, so i've got two alerts and input stay enabled. I want somekind of toggle effect, i wanted to know if it's possible.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event.

Comment: Both code blocks of your if/else statement are setting the button text to 'Save'.  Do you really want that or should one of them be setting it to 'Edit'?

Comment: just one of them, but the biggest problem is that it makes all things in the same time. It alert me 'editer' and 'sauvegarder' one after another (sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.Edit').live('click', function() {
    var el = $(this);   
        var r = $(".d"+el.attr("id"));
        if (el.hasClass('editMode')){
        el.removeClass('editMode');
                alert('sauvegarder..');
        r.attr("disabled", "disabled").css({
                    "background-color":"#FFF",
                    "border-color":"black"
                });
        el.text('Save').button("refresh");
    } else {
        el.addClass('editMode');
                alert('editer..');
        r.removeAttr("disabled").css({
                    "background-color","#FFF",
                    "border-color","red"
                });
        el.text('Save').button("refresh");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting what is `enabled` property. Also you can chain the event or cache it.

```
$('.Edit').on('click','.Edit', function() {
    if ($(this).text().valueOf()=="Save"){
        alert('sauvegarder..');
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".d"+id).prop('disabled', true)
                  .css({"background-color":"#FFF", "border-color":"black"});
        $(this).text('Save').button("refresh");
    } else if($(this).text().valueOf()=="Edit") {
        alert('editer..');
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".d"+id).prop('disabled', false)
                  .css({"background-color":"#FFF", "border-color":"red"});
        $(this).text('Save').button("refresh");
    }
}​);​
```

Answer (score 0):

You also may try such code for change disabled property:

...  $(".d"+id).attr('disabled', 'disabled').css(...) ....